# Copy selection from Google Sheets into a Google Doc (using REST API?)

Tags: rest, google-sheets, google-docs, google-sheets-api, google-docs-api

I have a Google Sheet whose contents I update with a python script that utilizes Google's REST API.

I want to copy a section of that Sheet into a given Google Doc automatically. (E.g. I want columns A:G of that sheet to appear in my Doc and get updated whenever the sheet does.) There are other elements (e.g. paragraphs) in the Doc, so it's important that the section appears in the location I specify each time (either by updating itself or by deleting the old section and inserting a new one).

Is that possible? How would I do it?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this is possible using [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) - [Extending Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs) and [Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets).
You can create a [Container-bound Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) that have a `onChange()` trigger to get the updated value.

Write to Docs

```
 //This can be openById() Open a document by ID.
 var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
 var body = doc.getBody();

 // Append a paragraph and a page break to the document body section directly.
 body.appendParagraph("A paragraph.");
 body.appendPageBreak();
```

Getting data from Sheets

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

 // This represents ALL the data
 var range = sheet.getDataRange();
 var values = range.getValues();

 // This logs the spreadsheet in CSV format with a trailing comma
 for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
   var row = "";
   for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
     if (values[i][j]) {
       row = row + values[i][j];
     }
     row = row + ",";
   }
   Logger.log(row);
 }
```

For implementation purposes, check the [link](https://opensourcehacker.com/2013/01/21/script-for-generating-google-documents-from-google-spreadsheet-data-source/). This shows how to create Google Docs and pass a value from Google Sheets using Apps Script.

Hope this helps.