# Copy / paste selection from google sheets into google docs via docs and sheets API?

Tags: node.js, google-sheets-api, google-docs-api

I want to transfer a selection from a google sheet document to a google docs document via my node.js backend service. I was hoping that the google docs API supports this feature, but I can't find the exact steps needed.

To visualize what I want to do, I have taken a simple screen capture in the web UI, that shows exactly what needs to happen - just not handheld, but automated in my backend service:
[image]

It is my understanding that the google web apps almost uses the exact same API as is exposed to developers, so I was hoping that someone here can tell me what exact requests are made for this to happen.

This question is somewhat similar: [Copy selection from Google Sheets into a Google Doc (using REST API?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44036428/copy-selection-from-google-sheets-into-a-google-doc-using-rest-api) but it 4+ years old, and haven't gotten much attention, and a lot have happened to the APIs in the meantime. Furthermore I am not interested in using app scripts, which the answer suggests doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to copy the values from Google Spreadsheet and paste them to Google Document as a table.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis for Node.js.
- You have already been able to use Sheets API and Docs API with Node.js.

If my understanding is correct, how about the following sample script?

I had the same situation as you. But unfortunately, at that time, I thought that this process might be a bit complicated. So I created a library of Node.js for achieving this. This sample script uses the library. [Ref](https://github.com/tanaikech/node-gdoctableapp)

### Usage:

#### 1. Install a library.

```
$ npm install --save-dev gdoctableapp
```

or

```
$ npm install --global gdoctableapp
```

#### 2. Prepare script.

In this sample script, please use your `auth` in your script. This `auth` is the same as Quickstart for Node.js. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs) But in this case, please set the scopes of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly` and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents`.

```js
const gdoctableapp = require("gdoctableapp"); // This is the library.

const spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
const documentId = "###"; // Please set your Document ID.

const sheets = google.sheets({ version: "v4", auth });
const { data } = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({ spreadsheetId, range: "'Sheet1'!A1:C3" }).catch((e) => console.log(e));
const values = data.values;
gdoctableapp.CreateTable(
  {
    auth,
    documentId,
    values,
    rows: values.length,
    columns: values[0].length,
    append: true,
  },
  (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
    console.log(res);
  }
);
```

- When this script is run, the values are retrieved from the cells `'Sheet1'!A1:C3` and put to the Google Document as a table. In this case, the table is appended to the Google Document.

### Node:

- This sample script supposes that you have already been able to use Sheets API and Docs API, and retrieve the access token for using the APIs. So please be careful about this.

### References:

- [node-gdoctableapp](https://github.com/tanaikech/node-gdoctableapp)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)

Comment: This looks great! I have both Sheets API and Docs API enabled, so I should be good to go. I assume the `gdoctableapp.CreateTable` returns a js object that defines the table in a way that docs understand? And I then have to use `batchUpdate` with a `InsertTableRequest` to insert it in my doc ?(https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#inserttablerequest) ?

Comment: @Rasmus Puls Thank you for replying. In this library, when my proposed script is used, the values are retrieved from Google Spreadsheet, and then, the retrieved values are put to the Google Document as a new table. So in this case, Docs API is used on the library side. The sample image can be seen at https://github.com/tanaikech/node-gdoctableapp#7-createtable

Comment: OK, Thank you. This seems to be a very useful resource of inspiration for exactly what I need to achieve.

Comment: @Rasmus Puls Thank you for replying. I had the same situation as you. So, at that time, I created this library because I thought that such a library might be also useful for other users. If this was useful for your situation, I'm glad.

Comment: Sure! Tanaike deserves a confirmation for that excellent answer